# Detection algorithm NOT based on sliding windows

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

In computer vision, does the detection task always have to be based on a sliding window principle?

Are there any references about alternatives to this principle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into feature (SIFT, SURF, ORB and such) based object detection?

Answer (score 0):

As Shekkizh said, there are some feature based algorithms like SIFT, SURF, ORB, BRISK, FREAK, etc... You can find some examples in OpenCV's tutorial, like the one there:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html#gsc.tab=0

Firstly, you find key points both in the template image and in the photo, and obtain feature descriptor for each key point; then, matching these key points; finally, you can use these corresponding pairs to calculate an homography matrix. Then you will know the position of the object in the photo.

Certainly there will be other detection algorithms that don't use sliding window. Hope this can give you some inspirations:)